# how to make the inline format (`[cite:@A]`) of org-cite into the correct format (`\cite{A}`) when export org file to latex file?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I try to use `org-cite` to deal with the latex pdf export.

However, by default, it convert format `[cite:@east_lisi_Allosteric2020; @gasiunas_siksnys_Cas92012]` to citation details instead of `\cite{east_lisi_Allosteric2020,gasiunas_siksnys_Cas92012}` when I try to export `org` format to `latex` format and further generate `PDF` files.

I try `[cite//b:@east_lisi_Allosteric2020; @gasiunas_siksnys_Cas92012]`, but it displays the same `tex` output.

Thus how could I get `\cite{east_lisi_Allosteric2020,gasiunas_siksnys_Cas92012}` when export `org` file to `tex`.

#### My org file:

```
#+LATEX_CLASS: article
#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [a4paper]
#+BIBLIOGRAPHY: ref.bib

* title 1
reference here these: [cite:@east_lisi_Allosteric2020; @gasiunas_siksnys_Cas92012]

* title 2
new
```

#### Bib file

```
@article{east_lisi_Allosteric2020,
  title = {Allosteric {{Motions}} of the {{CRISPR}}\textendash{{Cas9 HNH Nuclease Probed}} by {{NMR}} and {{Molecular Dynamics}}},
  author = {East, Kyle W. and Newton, Jocelyn C. and Morzan, Uriel N. and Narkhede, Yogesh B. and Acharya, Atanu and Skeens, Erin and Jogl, Gerwald and Batista, Victor S. and Palermo, Giulia and Lisi, George P.},
  year = {2020},
  month = jan,
  journal = {Journal of the American Chemical Society},
  volume = {142},
  number = {3},
  pages = {1348--1358},
  publisher = {{American Chemical Society}},
  issn = {0002-7863},
  doi = {10.1021/jacs.9b10521},
  urldate = {2020-09-11},
  keywords = {reading}
}

@article{gasiunas_siksnys_Cas92012,
  title = {Cas9\textendash{{crRNA}} Ribonucleoprotein Complex Mediates Specific {{DNA}} Cleavage for Adaptive Immunity in Bacteria},
  author = {Gasiunas, Giedrius and Barrangou, Rodolphe and Horvath, Philippe and Siksnys, Virginijus},
  year = {2012},
  month = sep,
  journal = {Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences},
  volume = {109},
  number = {39},
  pages = {E2579-E2586},
  publisher = {{National Academy of Sciences}},
  issn = {0027-8424, 1091-6490},
  doi = {10.1073/pnas.1208507109},
  urldate = {2020-06-08},
  chapter = {PNAS Plus},
  copyright = {\textcopyright{}  . Freely available online through the PNAS open access option.},
  isbn = {9781208507102},
  langid = {english},
  pmid = {22949671}
}
```

#### Default latex it exported:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\tolerance=1000
\author{nne}
\date{\today}
\title{}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\chapter{title 1}
\label{sec:org9b41159}
reference here these: (East, Kyle W. and Newton, Jocelyn C. and Morzan, Uriel N. and Narkhede, Yogesh B. and Acharya, Atanu and Skeens, Erin and Jogl, Gerwald and Batista, Victor S. and Palermo, Giulia and Lisi, George P., 2020,  Gasiunas, Giedrius and Barrangou, Rodolphe and Horvath, Philippe and Siksnys, Virginijus, 2012)

\chapter{title 2}
\label{sec:org4314d2e}
new
\end{document}
```

### What I need

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\tolerance=1000
\author{nne}
\date{\today}
\title{}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\chapter{title 1}
\label{sec:org9b41159}
reference here these: \cite{east_lisi_Allosteric2020,gasiunas_siksnys_Cas92012}

\chapter{title 2}
\label{sec:org4314d2e}
new
\end{document}
```